# how can i transfer information of one view to another?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

i have  designed a view in asp .net mvc3 off course registration form. This is very simple form having name ,father name , qualification and a submit button , after pressing submit button i want to display information by using another view. please suggest me how can i send information from one view to another view.

my controller class is :

```
namespace RegistrationForm.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
           // ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";

            //return View();
          return  RedirectToAction("registrationView");
        }

        public ActionResult About()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult registrationView()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

my view is :

@{
    Layout = null;
}

registrationView


    
    
      
           
              Enter Name

```
       </td>
       <tr>
       <td>
          Enter Father Name
       </td>
       <td>
        <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" />


       </td>
       <tr>
       <td>
          Enter Qualification
       </td>
       <td>
        <input type="text" name="qly" id="qly" />


       </td>

  </tr>
</table>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

well, we faced this problem before, and the best way to get this to work was to define a model that this page will work with, then use this model object when posting back, or redirecting to another view.

for your case, you can simply define this model in your Models folder

ex: `RegistrationModel.cs` file, and define your required properties inside.

after doing so, you will need to do 2 more steps:

1- in your GET action method, create a new `RegistrationModel` object, and provide it to your view, so instead of:

```
return View();
```

you will need something like:

```
var registrationModel = new registrationModel();
return View(registrationModel);
```

2- Use this model as a parameter in your `POST` Action method, something like

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult registrationView(RegistrationModel model)    
{
  // your code goes here
}
```

but don't forget to modify the current view to make use of the provided model. a time-saver way would be to create a new dummy View, and use the pre-defined template "Create" to generate your View, MVC will generate the properties with everything hooked up. then copy the generated code into your desired view, and omit any unneeded code.

this is a Pseudo reply. if you need more code, let me know

Answer (score 0):

[use ViewData to store the valu](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/12/06/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-3-passing-viewdata-from-controllers-to-views.aspx)e.
just remember that it will only last per one trip so if you try to call it again, the value would have been cleared.

```
namespace RegistrationForm.Controllers { public class HomeController : Controller { public ActionResult Index() { // ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";
    ViewData["myData"] = "hello world";

        //return View();
      return  RedirectToAction("registrationView");
    }

    public ActionResult About()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult registrationView()
    {
        // get back my data
        string data = ViewData["myData"] != null ? ViewData["myData"].ToString() : ""; 

        return View();
    }
}
```

And you can actually usethe ViewData value on the html/aspx/ascx after redirect to the registrationView.

For example on the registrationView.aspx:

```
<div id="myDiv">
my data was: <%= ViewData["myData"] %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<% using Html.Form("<ActionName>") { %>
    // utilize this HtmlHelper action to redirect this form to a different Action other than controller that called it.
<% } %>
```

Comment: it would still be equivalent... `code`@{ Html.BeginForm("<ActionName>"); } <!-- form fields --> @{ Html.EndForm(); }`code`

Answer (score 0):

You could simply in you method parameter list declare the parameters with the name of the controls. For example:

The control here has an id "qly"
`<input type="text" name="qly" id="qly" />`

Define your method parameter list as following:
`public ActionResult YourMethod(string qly)
{
//simply pass your qly to another view using ViewData, TempData, or ViewBag`, and use it in the desired view

`}`

Answer (score 0):

[You should use `TempData`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd394711.aspx) which was made exactly for it, to persist values between actions.

This example is from MSDN (link above):

```
public ActionResult InsertCustomer(string firstName, string lastName)
{
    // Check for input errors.
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(firstName) ||
            String.IsNullOrEmpty(lastName))
    {
        InsertError error = new InsertError();
        error.ErrorMessage = "Both names are required.";
        error.OriginalFirstName = firstName;
        error.OriginalLastName = lastName;
        TempData["error"] = error; // sending data to the other action
        return RedirectToAction("NewCustomer");
    }
    // No errors
    // ...
    return View();
}
```

And to send data to the view you can use the model or the `ViewBag`.