# Render.model in aspx

Tags: asp.net-mvc, scheduler

I'm working on sample program to show scheduler-net from this site:
http://scheduler-net.com/

I have a homepage developed with a controller.
Scheduler calender is in another controller.
Now i need to place the scheduler calender in the homepage of homepagecontroller.cs

I tried to transfer control from one action to another, but it is possible only under same controller.
according to this reference:
[how can i transfer information of one view to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6290742/how-can-i-transfer-information-of-one-view-to-another)

How can I place the scheduler calender developed from one controller to the homecontroller.
Or is that possible avoid calendercontroller.cs and place in the homecontroller itself.

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var scheduler = new DHXScheduler(this); //initializes dhtmlxScheduler
        scheduler.LoadData = true;// allows loading data
        scheduler.EnableDataprocessor = true;// enables DataProcessor in order to enable implementation CRUD operations
        return View(scheduler);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could render it as a partial in your view. Put this in views/Home/Index.cshtml:

```
@{
    Html.RenderAction("Index", "SchedulerController");
}
```

Obviously, replace Index and SchedulerController with the correct names.

Comment: already i redirect the home/index.cshtml to another view file in shared folder,This is the code in home/index.cshtml ,

`@{
    ViewBag.Title = "heading";
    Layout = "~/Views/_Layout.cshtml";
   
    }`

if i use the code u mentiond above,i get an error like this 
"HttpException was unhandled by user code.
Execution of the child request failed. Please examine the InnerException for more information."
 
_layout.cshtml is present in view/shared/_layout.cshtml


even if i place the above code in _layout.cshtml, i get the same exception